# ¿Cómo crear un nuevo nodo en C?

Tags: c, lista

Estoy declarando esta librería para una lista

```
#ifndef _Lista
#define _Lista

typedef struct
{ } nodoL;

// Alias para lista
typedef nodoL* lista;

void insFront(lista *L, int n);/* inserta el valor n al frente de la lista */
int mostrar(lista L);/* muestra por pantalla los valores de L, en forma recursiva */
void borrar(lista *L, int n);/*borra un elemento de la lista*/
#endif
```

Archivo myLista.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "myLista.h"

void insFront (lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = malloc(sizeof(nodoL)); //Crear un nuevo nodo.
    aux -> info = n;//Asignar el valor al nodo.
    aux -> sig = L; //Apuntar el nodo al nodo que apuntaba la lista.
    L=aux;//Hacer que la lista apunte al nodo nuevo.
    printf("Se agrego el %d a la lista\n",n); //Escribir en pantalla que se agregó el valor a la lista.
}/* inserta el valor n al frente de la lista */

int mostrar(lista L){
    //Crea y asigna 0 a la variable a devolver
    int i=0;
    //Preguntar si la lista no está vacía
    if (L!=NULL){
        //Asigna 1 a la variable devolver.
        i=1;
        //Muestra el valor actual en pantalla
        printf(" |%d|->",L->info);
        //Llama la función con el próximo valor.
        mostrar(L->sig);
    }
    //La función devuelve el resultado.
    return i;
    }/*muestra por pantalla los valores de L, en forma recursiva retorna 0 para lista vacía y 1 para la lista con elementos*/
```

> error: request for member 'sig' in something not a structure or union

```
void borrar(lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = *L; //puntero auxiliar al primer nodo
    *L = *L -> sig; //<-error: request for member 'sig' in something not a structure or union
    free (aux);   //elimino el primer nodo de la memoria
}
```

Tira estos error en la función insFront

> error: 'nodoL' has no member named 'info'
>
> error: 'nodoL' has no member named 'sig'

```
void insFront (lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = malloc(sizeof(nodoL));
    aux -> info = n; //<- aquí tira el error error: 'nodoL' has no member named 'info'
    aux -> sig = L; //<- y aquí error: 'nodoL' has no member named 'sig'
    *L=aux; 
    printf("Se agrego el %d a la lista\n",n);
}
```

Comment: Es una **TERRIBLE** idea llamar a los nodos listas. Las tuercas no son coches aunque uses tuercas para fabricar coches.

Answer (score 1):

> error: unknown type name 'nodoL'

La declaración de la estructura está así:

```
typedef struct nodoL
{ } * lista;
```

Es decir, declaras el alias `lista` como un puntero a una estructura de tipo `nodoL`... pero no declaras un alias específico para `nodoL`. En C los tipos basados en estructuras **deben** hacer uso de la palabra `struct`:

```
struct nodoL variable;
variable.info = 5;
```

Si no quieres repetir `struct` por todos lados tendrás que declarar el alias correspondiente. Quizás lo más limpio sería:

```
// Fijate que ahora el nombre va a al final
typedef struct
{ } nodoL;

// Alias para lista
typedef nodoL* lista;
```

Ahora ya podrás hacer algo tal que:

```
nodoL variable;
variable.info = 5;
```

> error: 'new' undeclared (first use in this function)

Como bien has comentado, `new` es una palabra propia de C++. En C tienes tres posibilidades a elegir:

- [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc): Reserva básica de memoria
- [`calloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc): Similar a `malloc`, inicializa todos los bytes a 0
- [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc): permite tanto reservar memoria como incrementar el tamaño de la memoria reservada previamente

Como tu estructura tiene un puntero, en aquellas situaciones en las que no vaya ser inicializado explícitamente dicha variabe puedes optar por usar `calloc`, pero para el uso del código que muestras te sirve con `malloc`:

```
lista aux = malloc(sizeof(nodoL));
aux -> info = n;//Asignar el valor al nodo.
aux -> sig = L; //Apuntar el nodo al nodo que apuntaba la lista.
```

> error: unknown type name 'delete'

El equivalente a `delete` en C es [`free`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free):

```
free(aux);
```

El resto de errores no los comento porque entiendo que se deben a una mala intrepretación del código por parte del compilador debido a los errores que te he indicado.

> error: request for member 'sig' in something not a structure or union

```
void borrar(lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = L; // (1)
    L = L -> sig;  // (2)
    delete aux;
}
```

Dos errores en este código:

1. `L` es un puntero doble y `aux` es un puntero simple.
2. `L` es un puntero doble, luego el operador `->` no está accediendo a la estructura `nodoL`

Lo correcto sería más bien esto:

```
void borrar(lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = *L;
//              ^
    *L = *L -> sig;
//  ^    ^
    free(aux); // Esto presupongo que ya esta corregido
}
```

Comment: Se pueden poner todos los alias en el mismo `typedef` es una práctica común en la [api de Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740(v=vs.85).aspx), así pues: `typedef struct { } nodoL, *lista;`

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster lo se... pero no me gusta definir varios alias en la misma línea :)

Comment: Cada uno con sus gustos :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si luego te pones a documentarlo con doxygen o similares queda una guarrería

Comment: Ese es el chiste... "si luego te pones a documentar". Llevo más de 10 años programando y el único código documentado que he visto ha sido el que he creado yo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster eso es porque muchas empresas no pagan por documentar sino por tirar líneas de código

Comment: Ahora me tira el siguiente `error: request for member 'sig' in something not a structure or union`

Comment: @AlejandroCaro He editado la respuesta. Para próximas preguntas sería intersante indicar en qué líneas te aparecen los errores.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro eso deberías ponerlo en la pregunta... los comentarios no son para iniciar una conversación de chat sino para exponer dudas respecto a la pregunta / respuesta correspondiente

Comment: Ya coloqué el error arriba. Me gustaría que pases y me lo corrijas, por favor

Comment: ¿Cómo se corrige o completa la estructura anterior para incluir las variables info  y sig

Answer (score 0):

Había varios errores, en la definición de estructura, etc.
Acá está completo y funcionado:

myLista.h

```
#ifndef _Lista
#define _Lista

typedef struct nodo
{
    int info;
    struct nodo *sig;
} nodoL;

// Alias para lista
typedef nodoL* lista;

void insFront(lista *L, int n);/* inserta el valor n al frente de la lista */
int mostrar(nodoL* L);/* muestra por pantalla los valores de L, en forma recursiva */
void borrar(lista *L, int n);/*borra un elemento de la lista*/

#endif
```

Archivo myLista.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "myLista.h"

void insFront (lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = malloc(sizeof(nodoL)); //Crear un nuevo nodo.
    aux -> info = n; //Asignar el valor al nodo.
    aux -> sig = *L; //Apuntar el nodo al nodo que apuntaba la lista.
    *L=aux; //Hacer que la lista apunte al nodo nuevo.
    printf("Se agrego el %d a la lista\n",n); //Escribir en pantalla que se agregó el valor a la lista.
}/* inserta el valor n al frente de la lista */

int mostrar(nodoL* L){
    //Crea y asigna 0 a la variable a devolver
    int i=0;
    //Preguntar si la lista no es vacia
    if (L!=NULL){
        //Asigna 1 a la variable devolver.
        i=1;
        //Muestra el valor actual en pantalla
        printf(" |%d|->",L->info);
        //Llama la función con el próximo valor.
        mostrar(L->sig);
    }
    //La función devulelve el resultado.
    return i;
}/*muestra por pantalla los valores de L, en forma recursiva retorna 0 para lista vacía y 1 para la lista con elementos*/

void borrar(lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = *L; //puntero auxiliar al primer nodo
    (*L) = (*L) -> sig; //hago apuntar l al siguiente nodo
    free(aux);   //elimino el primer nodo de la memoria
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "myLista.h"

int main()
{
    //Se declara y asigna una la variable paraa controlar la opción selecionada en el menú.
    int op=-1;
    //Se declara una lista.
    lista milista=NULL;
    //Mientras op se distinto de 0 (Cuando es op=0 finaliza el programa.
    while(op)
    {
        system("cls"); //Borrar la pantalla.
        //Mostrar en pantalla las opciones del menú.
        printf("\t\tEjemplo  con Listas\n\n\tSeleccione una opcion\n\n\t-1. Agregar elemento al frente\n\t-2. Mostrar lista\n\t-3. Borrar un elemento\n\t-0. Salir\n");
        scanf("%d",&op); //Captura el numero opción selecionada.
        switch(op){//Ir a la opción indicada por el usuario.
            //Ingresar un valor al comienzo de la lista.
        case 1:{
            int numNuevo;//Crear una variable para el numero a insertar en la lista.
            system("cls");//Borrar la pantalla.
            printf("Ingrese el numero para agregar a la lista:\n");//Pedir por pantalla un numero para insertar en la lista.
            scanf("%d",&numNuevo);//Capturar el número a insertar en la lista.
            system("cls");//Borrar la pantalla.
            insFront(&milista,numNuevo);//LLamara al procedimiento que inserta un numero al comienzo de la lista.
            getch(); //Esperar que el usuario presione una tecla.
            break;
        }
            //Mostrar la lista por pantalla.
        case 2:{
            system("cls");//Borrar la pantalla.
            //Mostrar en pantalla un titulo.
            printf("Los numeros cargados en la lista:\n\n");
            //Declarar un variable y asignarle el valor devuelto por la función  mostrar (0 Lista vacía 1Lista no vacia).
            int i = mostrar(milista);
            //Chequear si la lista esta vacía y mostrar en pantalla el exto que corresponda.
            if(i==0)printf("La lista esta vacia \n\n");
            else printf("# \n\n");
            //Esperar que el usuario presione una tecla.
            getch();
            break;
        }
            //Eliminar un número de la lista.
        case 3:{
                int n; //Crear un varible que almacene el número a borrar de la lista.
                system("cls");//Borrar la pantalla.
                printf("Ingrese el numero para borrar de la lista:\n"); //Pedir por pantalla un nuúmero para borrar de la lista.
                scanf("%d",&n); //Capturar el número a borrar de la lista.
                system("cls");//Borrar la pantalla.
                borrar(&milista,n); //LLamar a la función borrar.
                getch(); //Esperar que el usuario presione una tecla.
                break;
        }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```